# Do we really want people to ask "anything about personal computers"?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

So, we have a [pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pc) tag, which is described as being about "anything about personal computers." This tag is both quite vague and almost entirely off-topic. Can we remove this?

Comment: Apparently no, we cannot burn it :) Otherwise surely at some point in the creation of all those meta posts it would have succeeded.